# Out of memory when writing inside of function but not outside (R)

Tags: r, memory, data.table

I have monthly report files, each around 70MB. I wrote the following function to merge them into a single file:

```
fusionfil<-function(ruta){
  require(data.table)
  fusionfrag<-paste0(ruta,grep("_filt",dir(ruta),value = TRUE))

  datalist<-list()

  for(frag in fusionfrag){
    datalist[[frag]] <- fread(frag,colClasses="character")
  }

  datalist<-do.call(rbind,datalist)

  fwrite(datalist,"fusion.csv")
}
```

But it results in the following error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol) :
  Reached total allocation of 8082Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol) :
  Reached total allocation of 8082Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

However, if I take the final `fwrite` out and instead assign the function's output to a variable, I can then write it with no issue. I'd like to understand what's going on here (and if there's a more efficient way of achieving what I'm trying to do that'd be great too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing up some memory

```
gc()
```

before the call of `fwrite` to achieve the same effect.

UPDATED: I missed that the list and combined table had the same name.

Comment: If I `rm` datalist then how will `fwrite` know what to write? I tried something similar with the `datalist <- do.call(rbind,datalist)` line, which should, to my understanding, replace the no longer relevant list of data.tables with the merged object.

Comment: Okay, just adding `gc()` fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I missed that the list and combined table had the same name.